# Use mocha i a Nodejs-App without CLI

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I want to use Mocha (JS Testing) in a node-application whitout CLI.

If i do:

```
var mocha = require('mocha');
var test = new mocha();

test.run(function(err){
if(err){
    console.log("Found error");
}
});
```

I get Mocha run.

But how i can add a test?

i need something like this:

```
var testcase = {
before: function(){},
'Array': {
    '#indexOf()': {
        'should return -1 when not present': function(){
            [1,2,3].indexOf(4).should.equal(-1);
        }
    }
}
};

test.USE(testcase);
```

Comment: Mocha only supports loading tests from separate files: https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha/wiki/Using-mocha-programmatically